# issue in adding splash screen in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, splash-screen

I am creating the Xamarin iOS App on MAC OS X platform. I have successfully created a login page using Xcode. But now I want a splash screen before the login page. My Xcode is properly synced with Xamarin studio. I have added a screen with 120x120 Resolution to my project and added a splash screen as a launch image. But it's not selecting the image and nothing happens.
But now as a test I have added a new project in Xcode and added the same image as launch image and it successfully added. Please suggest what should be the issue and more important what is the solution. How can i add splash screen in my Xamarin iOS app?

Answer (score 3):

You need just to follow naming and size convention

```
IPHONE SPLASH
Default.png - 320 x 480
Default@2x.png - 640 x 960 
Default-568h@2x.png - 640 x 1096

IPAD SPLASH
Default-Portrait.png * — 768w x 1004h
Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png — 768w x 1004h
Default-Landscape.png ** — 1024w x 748h
Default-LandscapeLeft.png — 1024w x 748h
Default-LandscapeRight.png — 1024w x 748h
iPad-Retina–Portrait.png — 1536w x 2008h
iPad-Retina–Landscape.png — 2048w x 1496h
```

*—If you have not specified a Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png file, this file will take precedence.

**—If you have not specified a Default-LandscapeLeft.png or Default-LandscapeRight.png image file, this file will take precedence.

this link may be also helpfull for you: [App-Related Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)

Comment: can you please tell me... how to add splash screen in Xamarin.mac? Thanks :)